# snowflake show tables with cluster_by

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, clustering-key

I can use `show tables in <database name>` to show all tables in a database.
The results returned show if a table has clustering enabled - shows the `cluster_by` column.
Is there a way to get back a list of all tables that have value in cluster_by ?

The [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-tables.html) for show-tables shows only:

```
SHOW [ TERSE ] TABLES [ HISTORY ] [ LIKE '<pattern>' ]
                                  [ IN { ACCOUNT | DATABASE [ <db_name> ] | SCHEMA [ <schema_name> ] } ]
                                  [ STARTS WITH '<name_string>' ]
                                  [ LIMIT <rows> [ FROM '<name_string>' ] ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always ask **INFORMATION_SCHEMA**:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CLUSTERING_KEY 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE CLUSTERING_KEY IS NOT NULL;
```

or using **RESULT_SCAN**

```
SHOW TABLES IN DATABASE TEST;

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(result_scan(last_query_id())) 
WHERE "cluster_by" <> '';
```

Reference: [INFORMATION SCHEMA TABLES VIEW](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html), [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html)